# WCF Web API with windsor

Tags: wcf, api, rest, castle-windsor

Is there any contrib / sample using windosr as IoC for [WCF Web API](http://wcf.codeplex.com)?

I'm also looking for a integration between Windsor interceptor and WCF Web API interceptor(Microsoft.ServiceModel.Http.Interception.RequestInterceptor).

Thanks for any suggestions

Comment: I'm able to plug windsor but interceptor added to Service1 is not called 

var configuration = HttpHostConfiguration.Create() .SetResourceFactory(new WindsorResourceFactory(container.Kernel));

RouteTable.Routes.MapServiceRoute<WcfRestService1.Server.Service1>("Service1", configuration);

Comment: Please refer to the following blog post. http://blog.sharshag.com/2011/10/integrating-castle-windsor-in-wcf-web.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RequestInterceptor is part the REST starter kit and does not work with web api. You can intercept calls using our operation handlers (HttpOperationHandler). If you are using Windsor, then you will use Castle Dynamic Proxy to intercept When Windsor resolves the instance.

Answer (score 3):

I could be wrong but this did not work for me in the new version of WebAPI (.6).  I instead did this to hook up Windsor (warning this is probably not the best approach, however, it works).  Note _container is my Windsor Container.

```
 var config = new WebApiConfiguration()
                         {
                             CreateInstance =
                                 (type, instanceContext, httpRequestMessage) =>
                                     {
                                         return _container.Resolve(type);
                                     },
                             EnableTestClient = true,
                             ReleaseInstance = 
                                  (instanceContext, obj) => _container.Release(obj)
                         };
```

Comment: I'm using same solution with Windsor/web api6
About intercepting, I'm using web api interception strategy(MessageHandlers) for request concerns while I'm using Castle interceptor for ServiceContract/Api interception(aspect)